# Como configurar para que uma coluna seja composta no MySQL com Hibernate (Java)?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, crud

Estou fazendo um CRUD e na criação do meu modelo cheguei em um ponto que não consigo sair. Eu tenho uma tabela "Plano" e cada plano pode ter varias "Modalidades", como também vários "Extras", mas não sei como criar esses dois campos compostos utilizando Hibernate.

Eu estava criando os dois campos como um Objeto "Modalidade" e "Extra", mas notei que apenas 1 Modalidade e 1 Extra seria registrada na tabela "Plano", e caso o Plano estivesse mais de uma modalidade, a segunda não estaria na tabela "Plano".

[image: Segue um rascunho da estrutura]

```
public class Plano extends GenericDomain{

@Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
private String nome;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Short quanModalidade;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Short quanExtra;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String duracao; //Mensal,Semestre ou Anual

@Column(nullable = false, precision = 6, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal valor;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Short adquirentes;

@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
@ManyToOne
private Extra extra;

@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
@ManyToOne
private Modalidade modalidade;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public Short getQuanModalidade() {
    return quanModalidade;
}

public void setQuanModalidade(Short quanModalidade) {
    this.quanModalidade = quanModalidade;
}

public Short getQuanExtra() {
    return quanExtra;
}

public void setQuanExtra(Short quanExtra) {
    this.quanExtra = quanExtra;
}

public String getDuracao() {
    return duracao;
}

public void setDuracao(String duracao) {
    this.duracao = duracao;
}

public BigDecimal getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}

public Short getAdquirentes() {
    return adquirentes;
}

public void setAdquirentes(Short adquirentes) {
    this.adquirentes = adquirentes;
}

public Extra getExtra() {
    return extra;
}

public void setExtra(Extra extra) {
    this.extra = extra;
}

public Modalidade getModalidade() {
    return modalidade;
}

public void setModalidade(Modalidade modalidade) {
    this.modalidade = modalidade;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seu mapeamento esta errado, se um "plano" pode ter varias "modalidades" e "extras" deve usa o mapeamento [@oneToMany](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) no "plano" onde a modalidade e o extra armazenariam o id do plano de referencia na tabela sql exemplo simples

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso seja [@ManyToMany](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many), ou seja, O mesmo "plano" para varias "modalidades" e a mesma "modalidade" para varios "planos" deve se criar um tabela intermediaria para registrar essa relação.

Assim tem que existir uma tabela intermediaria para cada relacionamento (Plano_Modalidade) e (Plano_Extra) exemplo simples:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Obs: Dicas de @ManyToMany usando unidirecional ou bidirecional](https://www.devmedia.com.br/manytomany-hibernate-variacoes-unidirecional-e-bidirecional/29535)

Como Exemplo para o @ManyToMany seguindo a ideia deste Link: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many
Ficaria assim:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Plano")
public class Plano { 
    // ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Plano_Modalidade", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_plano") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_modalidade") }
    )
    List<Modalidade> modalidades;

    // getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Modalidade")
public class Modalidade {    
    // ...  

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "modalidades")
    private List<Plano> Planos;

    // getters/setters   
}
```

Comment: Estou utilizando a 2 opção que você sugeriu, em uma mesma tabela registrei a relação entre "Plano","Modalidade" e "Extra", logo eu tenho que inserir o @ManyToMany nessa tabela intermediaria, certo?

Comment: Esta tabela intermediária irá existir apenas na base da dados. No codigo o "Plano" terá @ManyToMany para "Modalidade" e outro para "Extra" E a "Modalidade" e "Extra", vão ter um "ManyToMany para o "Plano".
Este Mapeamento pode ter algumas variações sendo Unidirecional (So uma classe conhece o mapeamento) e Bidirecional (As duas classes conhecem o mapeamento).

Sugiro dar uma olhada neste link (https://www.devmedia.com.br/manytomany-hibernate-variacoes-unidirecional-e-bidirecional/29535) possuem alguns exemplos de como aplicar os dois casos

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com mais informações sobre como usar o @ManyToMany